# colgroup in razor WebGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is it possible to generate HTML markup for column group using the razor 'WebGrid' ?

I need a column group to be generated as part of the 'WebGrid' as the styling I am using relies on the results table generated in the view having 'colgroup' with a 'col' element for each column.

Thanks.

Comment: in the @Grid.GetHtml() you can set the rowStyle: "yourCssRowStyle"  - find more on following links: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/615776/WebGrid-in-ASP-NET-MVC4 and http://mvc-tutorials.com/styling-the-asp-net-mvc-webgrid

Comment: I don't see a HTML 'colgroup' being generated there (it is creating a 'thead' but what I'm looking for is 'colgroup') ...

Comment: Provide some code - it's hard to figure out what you're trying. Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9357957/606568 it should work on MVC 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found anything built into the `WebGrid` helper that lets us add a `<colgroup>` at design time. One hack I figured out to get around this was to append the HTML for my colgroups onto the table with jQuery:

```
<script type="text/template" id="col-group-template">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width:2em;" />
        <col style="width:15em;" />
        <col />
        <col style="width:15em;" />
        <col style="width:15em;" />
        <col style="width:12em;" />
    </colgroup>
</script>

<script>

    $(function () {

        var template = $('#col-group-template').html();

        $(template).appendTo('#items-grid');
    });

</script>
```

where `items-grid` is an `id` I assigned to this table. This assumes, obviously, that you already know the columns your grid needs; this worked for me since I had already built the grid template using plain HTML, but wanted the built-in paging & sorting the WebGrid provides.

Comment: Man, you're a genius! Thanks a lot, if this works it will save me a lot of time!