# How to increase cell width of MVC Grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcgrid

I am developing ASP.net MVC application.

I have used MVC Grid - Html Grid in it.
I want to increase the width of the columns but I cant. 
I dont want to change the Grid CSS.

I have mentioned width property twice but none of it works...

Here is my code.

```
 @model IEnumerable<StockWatchScreen.Controllers.Customer>
@using GridMvc.Html
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>
    <div class="listheading span9" style="font-size:22px;margin-bottom:30px;margin-left:0.10px">Customer</div>
    <hr />
    <div style="width:500px;">
        @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns => 
                    {
                        columns.Add(c => c.Code).Titled("Code");
                        columns.Add(c => c.Name).Titled("Name").SetWidth(500);
                        columns.Add(c => c.Address).Titled("Address");
                        columns.Add(c => c.OfficePhone).Titled("OfficePhone");
                        columns.Add(c => c.Email).Titled("Email");
                        columns.Add(c => c.FaxNo).Titled("FaxNo");
                        columns.Add(c => c.City).Titled("City");
                       }).WithPaging(4).Sortable(true).Filterable(true)  


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apply specific width in column of WebGrid in MVC3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357786/apply-specific-width-in-column-of-webgrid-in-mvc3)

Comment: CSS is how you define how markup should render, that is how you would define the column width. It is not an HTML thing, that just defines semantic structure to your data.

Comment: The .SetWidth(500); works for me, maybe you should remove <div style="width:500px;"> in front of the grid.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try changing

```
columns.Add(c => c.Name).Titled("Name").SetWidth(500);
```

to

```
columns.Add(c => c.Name).Titled("Name").SetWidth("70%");
```

or

```
columns.Add(c => c.Name).Titled("Name").SetWidth("100px");
```

Comment: Else  try it with attribute property something like: columns.Add(c => c.Name).Titled("Name").Attributes(style => "width:15%;");

Comment: It seems that  author issue was at 500px limitation at pattern `div`. That was already noticed by Steven