# how to adjust only first column width of the dynamic webgrid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I have the dynamic webgrid which binds the data from backend dynamically in  ASP.NET MVC..
    here i want to adjust the width of the first column in that dynamic webgrid.

```
<style>
    .webgrid-header a {
        color: white !important;

    }
    .webgrid-header th {
        text-align: center;

    }
</style>
@{
    var result = new List<dynamic>();

    foreach (var emprow in Model)
    {
        var row = (IDictionary<string, object>)new ExpandoObject();
        var eachEmpRow = (Dictionary<string, object>)emprow;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in eachEmpRow)
        {
            row.Add(keyValuePair);
        }
        result.Add(row);
    }
    var grid = new WebGrid(result, rowsPerPage: 50);
}

@if (@Model != null)
{
    @grid.GetHtml(
                htmlAttributes: new { id = "grdHoteling" },
                tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
        headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
        footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
        alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
        selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row", 
        rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All)
}
```

thanks...!!

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357786/apply-specific-width-in-column-of-webgrid-in-mvc3) might help

Comment: thank you.... stephen muecke...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Html.TextBox("PriceType"+(int)item.ShoppingCartID,(int)item.PriceType,new{@style="display:none;width:100px"})</span>),
```